# Variable gets lost between two html post methods or php functions

Tags: php, forms, scope, sql-update

I am quite new in php and trying to write my first scripts. I put values in a database. If a record has to be changed, the user can choose the id of the record that has to be changed. Some datas will remain, only read and some f.e. remarks can be changed. I have no problem with getting the datas from the database, but with storing the changed values.
User can choose the record to be changed:

```
public function bejelentesKivalasztas(){
        $this->kapcsolodas();
        $sqlHibabejelentesekTablabol    = "SELECT bejelentesID FROM hibarogzites";
        $this->hibabejelentesekTablabol = mysqli_query($this->kapcs, $sqlHibabejelentesekTablabol);
        $sorokSzama                     = mysqli_num_rows($this->hibabejelentesekTablabol);
        global $adat;
        global $i;
        $adat                           = [];
        print("<select class='textarea' name='bejelentes_ID' id='bejelentes_ID' style='width: 220px'>");
        for ($i=0; $i<$sorokSzama; $i++){
            $adat[$i]                   = mysqli_fetch_array($this->hibabejelentesekTablabol);
            print("<option value='" . $adat[$i]['bejelentesID'] . "'> " . $adat[$i]['bejelentesID'] . " </option>");
        }
    }
```

Necessary datas will be recalled and printed with the possibility to change some of them:

```
<?php
                    if(isset($_POST['bejelentesKivalasztas'])){
                        $bejelentesID       = $_POST['bejelentes_ID'];
                        $boltCimBeolvasas   = new adatlekerdezes($bejelentesID);
                        $boltCimBeolvasas   ->boltCimBeolvasas($bejelentesID);                      
                    }
                ?>
```

```
public function boltCimBeolvasas(){
        if(isset($_POST['bejelentesKivalasztas'])){
            $bejelentesID       = $_POST['bejelentes_ID'];
            $this->kapcsolodas();
            global $boltSzam, $boltVaros, $boltIrsz, $boltUtca, $bejelentesID;
            $this->bejelentesID         = $bejelentesID;
            $this->egyBoltkivalasztas();
            $sqlReadBoltAddressFromTable= "SELECT * FROM boltok WHERE boltID = '" . $this->boltID ."'";
            $boltCimBeolvasas           = mysqli_query($this->kapcs,$sqlReadBoltAddressFromTable);
            $this->adat2                = mysqli_fetch_array($boltCimBeolvasas);
            $this->boltSzam             = $this->adat2[1];
            $boltSzam                   = $this->boltSzam;
            $boltIrsz                   = $this->adat2[2];
            $boltVaros                  = $this->adat2[3];
            $boltUtca                   = $this->adat2[4];
            $this->bejelentesLehivas($this->bejelentesID);
            $this->megjegyzesBeolvasas($this->bejelentesID);
        }     
    }
    
    public function megjegyzesBeolvasas(){
        $this->kapcsolodas();
        global $bejelMegjegyz;
        $hibabejelentesekTablabol       = [];
        $this->sqlHibabejelentesekTablabol    = "SELECT megjegyzesSzoveg FROM hibarogzites where bejelentesID = '" . $this->bejelentesID . "'";
        $hibabejelentesekTablabol       = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($this->kapcs, $this->sqlHibabejelentesekTablabol));
        global $adat3;
        $adat3                          = [];
        $this->adat3                    = $hibabejelentesekTablabol;
        $bejelMegjegyz                  = $this->adat3[0];
        return $bejelMegjegyz;
    }
```

But when restoring should follow, the ID (bejelentesID) gets lost and as this, data will not change.

```
 public function bejelentesMod($intezkedes, $megjegyzes, $szerelo, $bejelentesID){
        $this->kapcsolodas();
        $sqlSzereloAdat     = "SELECT *
                                FROM    szerelo 
                                WHERE   szerelo_nev = '" . $szerelo . "'";
        $szereloAdat                = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($this->kapcs, $sqlSzereloAdat));
        print("Szerelőadat: " . $szereloAdat['szereloID'] . " eddig / ");
        $this->szereloID            = $szereloAdat['szereloID'];
        $this->intezkedesID         = $intezkedes;
        $this->bejelentesID         = $bejelentesID;
        print("intID: " . $this->intezkedesID);
        print(" / bejelID: " . $this->bejelentesID);
        $sqlHibabejelentesFrissites = "UPDATE hibarogzites SET megjegyzesSzoveg = '" . $megjegyzes . "', intezkedesID = '" . $this->intezkedesID . "', szereloID = '" . $this->szereloID . "', felhasznaloID = '" . $this->felhasznaloID . "' WHERE bejelentesID = '" . $this->bejelentesID . "'";
        $hibabejelentesFrissites    = mysqli_query($this->kapcs, $sqlHibabejelentesFrissites);
        print(', $sqlhibabejelentesFrissítés értéke: ' . $sqlHibabejelentesFrissites);
        if(!mysqli_connect_errno()){
            $this->message          = "A bejegyzés módosítva";
        }
        else{
            $this->message          = "A bejegyzés módosítása nem sikerült";
        }
    //    header('Location: hibabejelentesek.php');
    }
```

From that point that the id gets lost, the update cannot happen. I tried the mysql command at it worked in the sql programm directly. I inserted the

```
        print("intID: " . $this->intezkedesID);
        print(" / bejelID: " . $this->bejelentesID);
```

in function bejelentesMod to see what was the problem.

Maybe session can be the solution - but the id must be changed when another record must be changed. Can I use this session variable despite of that?

I suppose there are several problems with this code, but as I wrote - this is my first one. Even though I hope someone can me help how to get it work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I unfortunately don’t know what your problem is, but I can see a major red flag in that you are using class methods along with global variables. Although this is technically 100% valid, it is also almost always a sign of not fully understanding OOP. (Please don’t take that as an insult in anyway.) For instance, in the first block you’ve got `$i` for a loop index, and I can’t imagine a valid reason for that to be global.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I do not understand this OOP-thing. :) I wanted to pass the data adat[$i] - so I thought, then $i should also be global. :) I think the greatest problem of mine, I shortly solved - I passed the "lost" variable with $_SESSION, so now it does not get lost. And thanks for your comment!